# @DateTimeFormat with server's time zone

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datetime

I'm using Spring `@DateTimeFormatter` annotation on a `java.util.Date` as following:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm")
```

But it causes time-zone issues, because it uses the default UTC time zone. Is it possible, to force Spring, that use the server's locale settings?

Comment: this [discussion](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10495) on spring io JIRA might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered he same problem and solved it by using [Jodatime LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) (which is without time zone by design):

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate from
```

It can be converted to JDK Date by calling [toDate() method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDate--).

[Dependency for maven](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/dependency-info.html):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
   <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```